# Providing Panorama Stitcher with Camera Rotations

Tags: opencv, panoramas

When I capture images on a mobile device I can use the tilt-sensor and magnetometer to get the camera rotation matrix for each frame - or at least an initial estimate of it.

Is there a way to provide `Stitcher` or the "detailed-pipeline" these estimates for improving the convergence and results?

Looking at the code, the `Stitcher` class is probably not the way to go, it is too high level.
Presumably, there should be a way to feed these initial guesses to the Bundle-Adjuster, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: afaik `Stitcher` doesn't compute/estimate the extrinsic camera parameters but just computes homoghraphies, so I don't see a direct approach to use the known rotations. But maybe there are direct relations between homography computation and camera rotation (I don't know). The other approach could be to use a "bundle adjustment" method, which takes initial guesses for camera extrinsics and there you could get some improvements by using your known rotations.

Comment: Yes, that is my question, is there a way to get the initial camera estimates to the bundle adjuster and if so, how?

Comment: Most bundle adjuster use initial guesses, so yes, in theory it should be possible to use them. If openCV stitcher uses a bundle adjustment, you could have a look at the code (open source) and see where it is applied.

Comment: @Micka: I am. See my edits above.

Comment: sorry, I've got some experience in real time image stitching, but never used/implemented a bundle-adjuster myself yet, but maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: @Micka: Interesting. For your real-time stitching, did you use only `cv::Stitcher` or the detailed pipe-line? Did you not add motion sensor data?

Comment: Did that some time ago where there was no openCV stitching pipeline yet (some development version between openCV 1.1 and 2.0 afair). I only used image-to-image registration and no additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking both at the high-level Stitcher class and the detailed demo in samples/stitching_detailed.cpp, you would have to work here:

```
detail::HomographyBasedEstimator estimator;
estimator(features_, pairwise_matches_, cameras_);

...

bundle_adjuster_->setConfThresh(conf_thresh_);
(*bundle_adjuster_)(features_, pairwise_matches_, cameras_);
```

In a sense, you already have computed the homographies frame-by-frame. Therefore you can skip re-estimating homographies for all frames. When you set the cameras to you guesses, they are used by the bundle adjustment as initial guesses.

However, it doesn't seem that the current stitching pipeline can update only the (k-)newest frame(s). So this approach would work if you record a video and stitch the images together finally. If you wanted to stitch continuously, you'd have to construct a more complex pipeline.

Comment: Yes, I figured as much. Thanks.